# Why do I get this error when I try to use scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error.

> undefined method 'recent' for #

My codes are

**User controller**

```
@users = User.find_by_username(params[:id]).all_following.recent
```

**User model**

```
scope :recent, lambda { |n = 10| order("last_active_at DESC").limit(n) }
```

Comment: Please show the code that defines `all_following`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Thanks. Actually I'm using this gem `acts_as_follower` https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

if using lambda , should it be taking arguement ?? if you know exactly what the limit ,don't need to use lambda

try looking this guide on 
13.2
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-scopes

Answer (score 1):

From the gem documentation `all_following` is an array. This array may even be non-homogeneous.

The `recent` scope is really a method that can be called on an `ActiveRecord`.

I'm afraid the two don't match up and that's why the error says you can't call `recent` on an instance of an `Array`.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible using scope, because the all_following method will return an array, so it will not even look in the User model to try to find the scope. Another reason you should not use scope is that scope is for fetching items from the database in a particular way that you want to reuse, not sorting things. To get the functionality you want, I would add a method to the Array class like this:

```
class Array
  def recent(limit = 10)
    self.sort_by { |users| users[:last_active_at] }[0..(limit-1)]
  end
end
```

Then you can call `@users = User.find_by_username(params[:id]).all_following.recent(3)` in your controller, and pass in any value you want for the limit value. If you leave off the limit value, such as with `@users = User.find_by_username(params[:id]).all_following.recent`, then it will use 10 as the default.

Comment: Thanks for beautiful answer. Should I add those 5 lines to models/user.rb?

Comment: I would add these lines to a separate file in the lib directory to keep it separate from the model, since this is changing the array class rather than the user model. Make sure that if you put it in the lib directory that it is being automatically loaded by rails by having the line `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in your config/application.rb file. (If it isn't already there) You can place it in any file in the lib directory, and it should work!